# Coleman CT200U-EX-Will not start

Tags: ignition

Started up fine the first few times but when you hit the throttle it went wide open and when you let off the throttle it stayed wide open, so my son had to hit the kill switch to stop it. After doing this about 5 times it would not start back up. I figured out how to adjust the throttle to work properly, now it will not start. Did we damage something by hitting the kill switch while it was going wide open?

Comment: Pull the spark plug, it may be fouled and needs to be replaced. When the plug is out spin it over a bunch of times to clear any flooding that may have occurred.

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that shutting it down caused any damage.  More likely your carburetor is clogged up from old gasoline.

Take it apart and clean, or more likely replace, the jet, the venturi tube, and the float valve.  If the bowl is gummed up, clean that out too.